# How to hide category/item in android application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I have an native android application which is fetching data from opencart website, there are some categories/items that i don't want to display in the application.

I think this is the class which is handling the categories/items visibility

```
public class CategoryListActivity extends BaseActivity
{

List<Category>      categoryData            = new ArrayList<Category>();
ListView            categoryList            = null;
TextView            activityTitle           = null;
CategoryListAdapter categoryListAdapter     = null;
int                 categoryId              = -1;
String              categoryTitle           = "";
SharedPreferences   prefs                   = null;
ProgressDialog      loadingDialog;
String              currentParentHierarchy  = "";
```

Can somebody help?

Thank you

Comment: you can use item.setVisibility(gone);

Comment: Plz add some more data, and what you want hide exactly?